# how can I add multiple images using faker in Factory Laravel 9

Tags: arrays, laravel, factories

Please help, how can I add multiple url of images to the database using faker in Factory

```
public function definition()
{
    return array(
        'title' => $this->faker->colorName,
        'file_url' => $this->faker->imageUrl(748, 500),
    );
}
```

I didn't find a solution

Comment: What happens if you seed using this factory? You have exactly the right part from faker here

Comment: yes everything is right here but i need to add array  of images url like here:
["\/storage\/uploads\/CJbhk2P18IiKMJbd2neoD22X17dryLZXbqRty90e.jpg","\/storage\/uploads\/eWlnKOMfOF0Vd8Z37wLc5RlSQ6wOxgSt8VqXdqDR.jpg"]